# Open a new terminal to run remainder of the bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash


ip=$1
port=$2

if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
  echo "Enter 2 args: read_diags <IP address> <port number>."
  exit 1
fi

if ! command -v socat &> /dev/null
then
  echo "socat not found. Please install socat."
  exit
fi

clear


while :
do
socat UDP4-RECVFROM:$port,ip-add-membership=239.195.1.2:$ip,reuseaddr -
done
```

I would like to run the while loop in a new terminal. The script should return back to the original terminal where the script was spawned from. How can I do that in bash on ubuntu ? The output to stdout from socat should be visible as well.

Comment: You could put it in another script and call it by `./otherscript.sh`. To run it as another process, you might want `./otherscript.sh &`.

Comment: Thanks. I did think of that but then the output going to stdout in case its a command that prints output will be lost. I want to preserve the output to stdout. I updated my question for more clarity.